# nested ul horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists, alignment

This is my site:
http://www.clouderize.it/michele/

I am changing my header and I would align the second bar and give the same width (violet background), to the first bar menu (grey buttons).

I have understand how to do.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give `position: relative` to `#primary-nav-` (or to `div.nav-` is fine too)
and `width: 960px` to `.submenu`

The resulting effect (done via firebug) is

[image: bars aligned]